# NSAttributedString Not Working - Does not appear when compiled for Distribution

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

This code works in the simulator and connected devices via USB port. It does not work when the app is compiled for distribution (Target:IOS 6.1, Xcode 5.1.1) and downloaded as .ipa

Any idea why? Has anyone seen this? Have a workaround?

```
#import "UILabel+UILabel_decoratedText.h"

@implementation UILabel (UILabel_decoratedText)

+ (UILabel *)decoratedText:(NSString *)string
                        font:(UIFont *)font
                       color:(UIColor *)color
                   container:(CGRect)container
              shadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffsetSize
               shadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor
          shadowBlurRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius
                    tag:(NSUInteger)tagInteger
{

    CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:container.size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(container.origin.x, container.origin.y, container.size.width, size.height)];
    label.text = string;
    label.font = font;
    label.textColor = color;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.tag = tagInteger;

    NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
    [shadow setShadowColor: shadowColor];
    [shadow setShadowOffset: shadowOffsetSize]; // CGSizeMake(-1.0f, 1.0f)
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius: blurRadius];

    NSAttributedString *attributedString;

    if ((string != nil) && (![string isEqualToString:@""])) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color,
                                       NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                       NSShadowAttributeName: shadow
                                       };
        attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:dictionary];
        label.attributedText = attributedString;
    }
    return label;
}

@end
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: First thing I would do is put in code to verify that the line `label.attributedText = attributedString` is reached, and that `label` and `attributedString` are not `nil`.  Then (just for debugging) throw up a `UIAlertView` if something is amiss.

Comment: What doesn't work? Which version of iOS does it not work on?

Comment: Nothing appears on screen. All values are non-nil and framed correctly.

Comment: After some research I found that UILabel with multiline AttributedString was broken and I rewrote this using UITextView instead. Will put up a better answer when I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running into a bunch of issues with multi-line UILabel and NSAttributedString I changed my UILabel to UITextView and everything worked. You can search SO And Google for UILabel, NSAttributedString and issues and you'll get a few hits.

Comment: I was generating an NSAttributedString from HTML using `-[NSString initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:]` and setting a UILabel's attributedText property resulted in un-styled text. Using a UITextView everything displays properly. Thanks!